# Using user defined literals at run runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, literals

I am trying to use user defined literals at runtime.

Instead of hard coding the literal at compile time, I would like to specify the value at runtime.

I created [this](http://cpp.sh), but now cannot progress.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Degrees
{
    double degree_;

public:

    explicit Degrees(long double degree) : degree_(degree) {}

    double GetValue() const { return degree_; };
};

Degrees operator "" _deg(long double degree)
{
    // Returns radians
    return Degrees(degree * 3.14159265358979323846264L / 180);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long double angle;
    std::cin >> angle;

    Degrees degrees(angle);

    //degrees = 3.1_deg;

    std::cout << degrees.GetValue() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question?  What challenge is stopping you?

Comment: @NathanOliver setting the literal at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can call a user-defined literal like a normal function:

```
degrees = operator""_deg(angle);
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `degrees = operator""_deg(angle);` instead? It doesn't make sense to invoke the operator like this when passing it a literal value. Honestly though, I would not recommend invoking an operator manually like that at all. Move the conversion to a separate function and call that directly instead, and then have the operator call the same function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau please can you show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the distinction between radian and degree you probably want either

- two constructors with tag dispatch `Degrees(double rad, RadiantTag)` and `Degrees(double deg, DegreeTag)`, or
- one constructor `Degrees(double angle, AngleUnit unit)` where `enum AngleUnit { Rad, Deg };`, or
- static functions `Degrees Degrees::fromDeg(double deg);` and `Degrees Degrees::fromRad(double rad);`

and call one of those from your literal operator. Of course you can just call the literal operator as a normal function on non-literal values but they are called literals for a reason, imo.

Off topic: your argument names in your constructor are confusing. Does it accept radians or degrees? Your name suggests degrees but your literal operator passes radians.